# Read a maze from a txt file in java

Tags: java, arrays, maze

I want to read a maze which contains 1s and 0s and store it in an array.This is what i have done so far :

```
while(line!=null){
   char[] ch = line.toCharArray();
   for(int i = 0;i < ch.length;i++){
       maze[i][num] = ch[i];
   }
   num++;
}
```

i am not sure about this code.Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you unsure about it?  What does it do wrong?

Comment: This while loop is infinite. Where do you update the line?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The reason your line is always not null is because you do not update it.

At first, your while checks if it is null and since the value of the line never changes, it will loop forever.

```
while(line!=null){
   char[] ch = line.toCharArray();
   for(int i = 0;i < ch.length;i++){
       maze[i][num] = ch[i];
   }
   num++;
   line = //The value of your next line
}
```